# Swift 4 - Public modifiers cannot be used in protocols

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

[image]

If public modifiers cannot be used in protocols, then why does the SDK have protocols that has methods that are public?

[image]

Comment: The protocol is declared public, so all properties and functions declared by it will also be public (and cannot be changed). IIRC the ability to set different levels was removed in swift 1.2 or 2.0.  As for why the sdk has public, I believe that it's because source kit is generating that code from the library and is inserting keywords everywhere.

Comment: The diagnostic will be slightly more informative in a future version of the language: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Objective-C:

```
@protocol TaskManagerProtocol
@optional
- (void) test;
@end
```

Now look at the Swift generated interface:

```
public protocol TaskManagerProtocol {
    optional public func test()
}
```

That is the phenomenon you're seeing in the headers.